# calling Static Method from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, fusioncharts

I need to create charts based on the selection of value in the dropdown.

I'm pulling value from database based on the selected value and displaying data in charts and graphs (Google charts or any java script based charts).

But on calling from javascript, the code behind method need to be static.

if the method is static, then the data will be saved on memory and in case of multi user site, the users may get inappropriate charts.

Which means, the users will gets only the recent data saved in the memory recently.

Kindly suggest how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please see the example in below url. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-HTML5-Canvas-charts-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: This is ajax and data will  not be in memory every user will see data which is saved in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to have an static method. It's not strictly necessary.

Anyway, if you need to store the data in memory (no matter if it's an static method) you can use Cache for your application. It's basically a dictionary. Then, at some point, you need to identify the user with your application in order to differentiate the data in memory. If you have an authentication module, maybe the key can be the identity of the user. If not, send a cookie to the client with an unique value, like a DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(). This can be a safe way to identify your user.

All the JS calls always sends the cookies. That's the way you can identify and differentiate the data in memory.

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for your response. If the method is non static and its doesn't contains Web method tag, then those methods are not available to make a call from the java script. Only static method gets called from javascript.

Comment: More over in my case i don't want to save any data in memory. I told the behavior of static method, which saves the data in memory in default.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You are using Webforms on server side. Yes, one solution is to use static methods for javascript consumption, but I don't know why you point about "saves the data in memory". Can you give more details on your question? It's the first time I hear of something like this.

Comment: In the context of a web application static methods which is shared across all request threads and stays in memory. That means that if two requests are both processing and each try to set the static piece of data, you have a race condition (and threading problems potentially).

Comment: Yes, but your problem is only for getting values from database, then its thread safe. If you plan to set static variables then you can have race conditions. Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benchr/archive/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you.aspx, or I'm missing something? As far as I can see, your method only have to return data from server. Your method is safe as long as It does not depend on static variables outside of your static method.